# Energy dependent Cross section - Observation of a resonance

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, experimental-technique, scattering-cross-section

In High energy/Hadron physics experiments, when observing new decay channels.  they use two different approaches.

Take for example : 
Y(4260) -> J/psi pi+ pi-
In Babar, They observed the Y(4260) in the missing mass of (J/psi pi+ pi-)
[image]
In BESIII, They investigate the cross section dependent energy of (e+ e- -> J/psi pi+ pi-) and they observed two different resonances structures

[image]
Could you please explain to me the idea behind using the energy dependent cross section instead of the invariant mass to determine which resonance decayed to J/psi pi+ pi- ?

Comment: "in the missing mass of (J/psi pi+ pi-) " you must mean "in the invariant mass"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once one knows all four vectors of  the decay products in an event, one can accumulate in a plot the invariant mass  of (J/psi pi+ pi-) from each event and get the resonance clearly.

In annihilation experiments , as with e+e- annihilation into hadrons,if the quantum numbers allow it, a resonance in the total crossection as a function of center of mass energy appears at the correct mass.  [Here is a scan](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/hadronic-xsections/rpp2014-sigma_R_ee_plots.pdf) from low to high energies, where the channel you show is just a small bump with respect to the much stronger psi resonances.

[image: epl]

The reason resonances appear in total hadronic annihilation cross sections if the quantum numbers allow it, is because the probability is high due to the form of the crossection as a [function of energy.](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2010/reviews/rpp2010-rev-cross-section-formulae.pdf)

[image]

In this formula, essentially a [Breit Wigner](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/parlif.html),  $E0=m_0c^2$ is the mass of the resonance and E is the squareroot(s) in the plot above..